# How to test std::bitset for randomness?

Tags: c++, testing, random, bitset, std-bitset

I create random bitsets with following code below. Now I wanna write some test and asking myself how to test the randomness of bitsets? Is there a good solution to this problem?

As bitsets can not be represented as numbers AFAIK, I don't know hot to apply some sort of test like chi-square or whatever.

Should I count the ocurrences of 1s and 0s like

```
 1001
+0101
+1110
+0010
 ----
 2222 = good as half of 4 (bitsets) equal 2
```

Are there other ways?

```
template <size_t N>
using bitset_t = std::bitset<N>;
```

and

```
template <size_t N>
struct random_bitset_t
{
  static_assert(N % 64 == 0, "random_bitset_t<N> only with N % 64 == 0");

  std::bitset<N> operator()() const;
};

template <size_t N>
std::bitset<N> random_bitset_t<N>::operator()() const
{
  static thread_local std::mt19937 g{std::random_device{}()};

  static thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t> d;

  std::bitset<N> bitset;

  for (int i=0,j=N/64; i<j; ++i)
  {
    bitset <<= 64;

    bitset |= std::bitset<N>(d(g));
  }
  return bitset;
}
```

and

```
template <size_t N>
using bitsets_t = std::vector<bitset_t<N>>;
```

and

```
template <size_t N>
struct random_bitsets_t
{
  random_bitsets_t(size_t);

  bitsets_t<N> operator()() const;

  size_t size;
};

template <size_t N>
random_bitsets_t<N>::random_bitsets_t(size_t size)
: size(size)
{}

template <size_t N>
bitsets_t<N> random_bitsets_t<N>::operator()() const
{
  bitsets_t<N> bitsets;

  bitsets.reserve(size);

  std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(bitsets),size,random_bitset_t<N>());

  return bitsets;
}
```

Comment: You _can_ get a number from a bitset, using e.g. [`std::bitset::to_ullong`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ullong).

Comment: Of course you can interpret a bitset as a number, one way would be to do `if (bitset[n]) number += 1 << n;` for all the bits. Once you have that you use some [standard randomness tests](http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~xmeng/Course/CS6337/Note/master/node42.html).

Comment: There is no test for randomness on a single set, since all outcomes should be equally likely.  You can test many trials and make sure there is a Poisson distribution.

Comment: It depends which part you suspect of not being uniformly or whatever. You might want to go like "is there a bias for a 0 or 1 if the last digit was a 0?" Or "..if there was a certain set of digits". In any case, you need a big amount of generated numbers for a test.

Comment: @stark Poisson distribution??? That's not really a distribution you commonly associate with random number theory...

Comment: @PaulUszak the main thing to test for random number generator is not even distribution, it is independence.

Answer (score 0):

Write out (sequentially) all the bits from many loops to a binary file. Try to write about 500KB of data. Then learn to use existing tools like ent.  You'd do ent -b filename and see if you get good results.  This is a standard test.

When you get better at it, try Diehard.  That needs about 10MB of test data but is a lot harder to reliably understand.

Caveat.

Since you're running the Mersenne Twister, you only need to validate your bitset creation routine.  The Twister implementation should already have been vetted.  You shouldn't need Diehard as your bitset generator will have been sufficiently tested by ent.